# How to properly call a function/url from html using AJAX in Django?

Tags: python, jquery, html, django, ajax

I am trying to display a User's name on top of a box where they enter their Employee # in a form, without having to refresh the page.

For example, they enter their # and then after they click/tab onto the next field, it renders their name on top, which comes from the database, so the user knows they've entered the correct info. This name is stored in a separate model, so I try to retrieve it using the "id/number".

I am not too familiar with AJAX but after reading a few similar questions it seems like an AJAX request would be the most appropriate way to achieve this. I tried to make a function **get_employee_name** that returns the name of the person based on the way I saw another ajax request worked, but I'm not sure how to implement this so it displays after the # is entered.

My page currently loads, but when I check the network using F12, there is never a call to the function/url that searches for the name to display it on the page. I'm not sure where I might be missing the part that connects these two areas of the code, but I have a feeling it has to do with the html tag where the call is supposed to happen, as I am not too familiar with html and Django.

**models.py**

```
class EmployeeWorkAreaLog(TimeStampedModel, SoftDeleteModel, models.Model):
    employee_number = models.ForeignKey(Salesman, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, help_text="Employee #", null=True, blank=False)
    work_area = models.ForeignKey(WorkArea, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=False)
    station_number = models.ForeignKey(StationNumber, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True,  blank=True)
```

This is the model where the name is stored

**alldata/models.py**

```
class Salesman(models.Model):
    slsmn_name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    id = models.IntegerField(db_column='number', primary_key=True)
```

I was reading I can add to the "attrs" in the widget an 'onchange' part, but I am not too familiar with how to approach this and tying it to the ajax request from forms and not the html.

**forms.py**

```
class WarehouseForm(AppsModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = EmployeeWorkAreaLog
        widgets = {
            'employee_number': ForeignKeyRawIdWidget(EmployeeWorkAreaLog._meta.get_field('employee_number').remote_field, site, attrs={'id':'employee_number_field'}),
        }
        fields = ('employee_number', 'work_area', 'station_number')
```

**views.py**

```
def enter_exit_area(request):
    form = WarehouseForm(request.POST or None)

    if form.is_valid():

        # Submission stuff/rules

    return render(request, "operations/enter_exit_area.html", {
        'form': form,
    })


def get_employee_name(request):
    employee_number = request.GET.get('employee_number')

    try:
        employee = Salesman.objects.get(id=employee_number)
    except Salesman.DoesNotExist:
        return JsonResponse({'error': 'Employee not found'}, status=404)

    employee_name = employee.slsmn_name
    return JsonResponse({'employee_name': employee_name})
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'enter-exit-area/$', EnterExitArea.as_view(), name='enter_exit_area'),

    path('get-employee-name/', views.get_employee_name, name='get_employee_name'),
]
```

The ajax request I tried to create is at the end of this html. I modified a similar request I found, but it does not actually display anything on the screen, not sure if I'm missing an area where the request is actually never being called, as I am not too familiar with how these types of requests work.

**enter_exit_area.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block main %}
    <form id="warehouseForm" action="" method="POST" novalidate >
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div>
            <h1 id="employee_name">{{ employee_name }}</h1>
            <div>
                {{ form.employee_number.help_text }}
                {{ form.employee_number }}
            </div>
            <div>
                {{ form.work_area.help_text }}
                {{ form.work_area }}
            </div>
        </div>

        <div>
            <div>
                <button type="submit" name="enter_area" value="Enter">Enter Area</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>

    <script>
        $("#id_employee_number").change(function () {
            var employee_number = $(this).val();
            var url = $("#warehouseForm").data("employee-name");

            $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type:'GET',
            data: {
                'id': employee_number
            },
            success: function (data) {
                var employee_name = data['employee_name'];
                $('#employee_name').text(employee_name);
            },
            error : function (data) {
                var error_message = data['error'];
                $('#employee_name').text(error_message);
            }
            });
        });
    </script>
{% endblock main %}
```

What could be causing nothing to render on the page? Is there a call missing in the html portion? I don't know if `<h1 id="employee_name">{{ employee_name }}</h1>` is the proper way to call the function for display. I'm not getting any errors as it does not seem to be getting called at all whatsoever.

Is there a better/more efficient way to accomplish this type of call?

Comment: I've only had a quick glance, so I don't yet fully grasp how everything is supposed to fit together, but I see two very obvious problems in your JS: 1) you send the Ajax on a `change` event for `$("#id_employee_number")`, but there is nothing in your html with this ID. (This is presumably why you don't see any request being sent in your network tab.) 2) even if you fixed that, your url is `$("#warehouseForm").data("employee-name");`. Although ``$("#warehouseForm")` certainly exists this time, it has no `data-employee-name` attribute.

Comment: You are not passing the `{{ csrf_token }}` in the ajax request. Your server must be receiving forbidden requests

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm late, but here's the answer:

I would use GET instead of POST as you are only retrieving data from the url.

**views.py**

```
def get_employee_name(request, employee_number):
    try:
        employee = models.Salesman.objects.get(id=employee_number)
    except models.Salesman.DoesNotExist:
        return JsonResponse({'error': 'Employee not found'}, status=404)

    employee_name = employee.slsmn_name
    return JsonResponse({'employee_name': employee_name})
```

**urls.py**

```
app_name = 'operations'

urlpatterns = [
    path('enter-exit-area/', views.enter_exit_area, name='enter_exit_area'),
    path('get-employee-name/<int:employee_number>',
         views.get_employee_name, 
         name='get_employee_name'
    ),
]
```

**enter_exit_area.html**

```html
{% extends "operations/base.html" %}

{% block main %}
    <form id="warehouseForm" action="" method="POST" novalidate >
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div>
            <h1 id="employee_name"></h1>
            <div>
                {{ form.employee_number.help_text }}
                {{ form.employee_number }}
            </div>
            <div>
                {{ form.work_area.help_text }}
                {{ form.work_area }}
            </div>
        </div>

        <div>
            <div>
                <button type="submit" name="enter_area" value="Enter">Enter Area</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>

    <script>
        $("#id_employee_number").change(function () {
            var employee_number = $(this).val() || 0;
            var url = "{% url 'operations:get_employee_name' 0 %}".replace('0', employee_number);
            console.log(url);
            $.ajax({
              url: url,//your url was incorrect
              type:'GET',
              success: function (data) {
                  var employee_name = data['employee_name'];
                  $('#employee_name').text(employee_name);
              },
              error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                $('#employee_name').text(jqXHR.responseJSON.error);
              }
            });
        });
    </script>
{% endblock main %}
```

P.S. You have to define `app_name` in app's `urls.py`.

Comment: Hi! app_name was defined, just forgot to include under file. I made the changes you suggested but I'm noticing that still there is no call being made to the script at all. I have another script that renders a dropdown that does create a call when I interact with it, which is how I'm noticing that typing the employee number does not trigger it

Comment: Are you including jquery ?@MarianaGomez-Kusnecov

Comment: Try removing `ForeignKeyRawIdWidget`. I think as you are setting a new id to the field. That is not triggering the `change` event. @MarianaGomez-Kusnecov